# Box pattern made of Xs and Os in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a box pattern in java with a pattern that looks like

```
xoxox
o   x
oxoxo
```

I can get close with alternating x and o on the top and bottom, but there is a line of Os in between that I'm struggling to get rid of. Here is my code so far:

```
public static String textBoxString(int rows, int cols, char c1, char c2) {
        char temp = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                if (i == 1 || i == rows) {
                    System.out.print(c1);
                    temp = c1;
                }
                if (temp == c1) {
                    System.out.print(c2);
                    
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        String sideString = Integer.toString(rows, cols);
        return sideString;
    }
```

Outputs:

```
xoxoxoxoxo
ooooo
xoxoxoxoxo
```

Comment: I mean this sincerely:  the biggest thing you can do to help yourself with these kinds of bugs is to learn how to run your code in a debugger.   Are you using an IDE of any kind to write your code?   If so it very likely has a debugger.  If you're not using and IDE (IntelliJ or Eclipse, etc.) then I highly recommend that you start using one.  Good luck.

Comment: Only print `c1` or `c2` if in first _or_ last row (you have that) _or_ first _or_ last column. Else print space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternate implementation that uses a `repeat()` method to reduce repetitive code.

This code correctly prints alternating characters around the border. See tests at the end for proof that it works for any combination of odd/even numbers of rows and columns.

Solution for Java 11+:

```java
public static void textBoxString(int rows, int cols, char c1, char c2) {
    System.out.println((String.valueOf(c1) + c2).repeat(cols / 2 + 1).substring(0, cols));
    String spaces = " ".repeat(cols - 2);
    for (int i = 2; i < rows; i++)
        System.out.println((i % 2 == 0 ? c2 : c1) + spaces + ((i + cols) % 2 == 0 ? c1 : c2));
    System.out.println((rows % 2 == 0 ? String.valueOf(c2) + c1 : String.valueOf(c1) + c2).repeat(cols / 2 + 1).substring(0, cols));
}
```

Same logic, but for any Java version, using a local `repeat()` helper method:

```java
public static void textBoxString(int rows, int cols, char c1, char c2) {
    System.out.println(repeat(String.valueOf(c1) + c2, cols / 2 + 1).substring(0, cols));
    String spaces = repeat(" ", cols - 2);
    for (int i = 2; i < rows; i++)
        System.out.println((i % 2 == 0 ? c2 : c1) + spaces + ((i + cols) % 2 == 0 ? c1 : c2));
    System.out.println(repeat(rows % 2 == 0 ? String.valueOf(c2) + c1 : String.valueOf(c1) + c2, cols / 2 + 1).substring(0, cols));
}
private static String repeat(String s, int count) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        buf.append(s);
    return buf.toString();
}
```

*Tests*

```java
textBoxString(3, 5, 'x', 'o');
textBoxString(4, 5, 'x', 'o');
textBoxString(4, 6, 'x', 'o');
textBoxString(5, 6, 'x', 'o');
```

*Outputs*

```
xoxox
o   o
xoxox
```

```
xoxox
o   o
x   x
oxoxo
```

```
xoxoxo
o    x
x    o
oxoxox
```

```
xoxoxo
o    x
x    o
o    x
xoxoxo
```

Answer (score -1):

This flow will solve your problem :

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

// The main method must be in a class named "Main".
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
                var result = textBoxString(4,6,'x','o');
        System.out.println("Hello world!");
    }
    
      
    public static String textBoxString(int rows, int cols, char c1, char c2) {
        char temp = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                char toPrint = j%2==0?c1:c2;
                boolean isEmpty=true;
                if ((i == 1 || i == rows) || (i >1 && i < rows &&(j==1 || j==cols))) {
                    isEmpty=false;
                }
                
                
                if (!isEmpty) {
                    System.out.print(toPrint);
                    
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();

        }
        String sideString = Integer.toString(rows, cols);
        return sideString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Result is incorrect, since the characters don't alternate down the sides.

Answer (score -1):

I hope you need something like this

```java
    public static String textBoxString(int rows, int cols, char c1, char c2) {
        char temp;
        for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
                if (1 == i || rows == i) {
                    System.out.print(c1);
                    System.out.print(c2);
                } else if (1 == j) {
                    System.out.print(c1 + " ");
                } else if (cols == j) {
                    System.out.print(" " + c2);
                } else {
                    System.out.print("  ");
                }
            }
            temp = c1;
            c1 = c2;
            c2 = temp;
            System.out.println();
        }
        return Integer.toString(rows, cols);
    }
```

Comment: or using single line 
`System.out.print((1 != i && rows != i) ? 1 != j ? cols != j ? "  " : (" " + c2) : (c1 + " ") : (c1 + "" + c2));`

Comment: Result is incorrect, since it prints double the number of columns, which prevents it from printing an odd number of column, like the 5 shown in the question.

Answer (score -1):

I'd write it as:

```
  public static String textBoxString(int rows, int cols, char c1, char c2) {
    String box = "";
    boolean firstChar = true;
    for(int row=1; row<=rows; row++){
      for(int col=1; col<=cols; col++) {
        box = box + ((row==1 || row==rows || col==1 || col==cols) ? (firstChar ? c1 : c2) : " ");
        firstChar = !firstChar;
      }
      box = box + System.lineSeparator();
    }
    return box;
  }
```

Comment: *FYI:* You should probably use [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator--) instead of hard-coding a plain `\n`.

Comment: @Andreas How is it "incorrect" for an even number of columns?  The specification wasn't very specific on how the "alternating" should occur, and if you look at their examples, the up/down alternating isn't consistent.  I simply continued the alternation from the previous row into the next.  =)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the `lineSeparator()` tip, I'll make that change.

Comment: I told you it's wrong for even numbers, so did you **try it for yourself** to see what happens? I shouldn't have to explain it, since the code will clearly show the problem when you run it!!! E.g. you could have used the 4 test cases shown in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64070789/5221149), or done your own test case with an even number of columns. --- When `cols` value is odd, this code prints the sides as alternating lines of `o     o` and `x     x`, but when the `cols` value is even, the sides are ***all*** `x     o`, with *no alternating*.

Comment: Wow...you have made some serious ASSUMPTIONS about how the box should be drawn.  Are you the teacher who gave this assignment?  The author did not give a clear specification for how the alternating should occur.  I've interpreted it differently.  End of story.  My code alternates characters from left to right, continuing on the next row and through the spaces.  How about YOU look again at the box in the original post at the VERY top, that he said they were trying to reproduce.  It does NOT have alternating chars going up/down on the edges.

Comment: Not "End of story" because you have very inconsistent interpretation of how the sides should be printed. You can make whatever interpretation you want, but you haven't, or rather the code doesn't do the sides in any interpretation, unless you decided that sides are *undefined* and can be whatever arbitrary result the code happens to do, but having the code entirely different for odd vs even number of columns is just wrong. The sides are certainly **not** "alternating from left to right", so I stand by my assessment: **Result is incorrect**, by *whatever* interpretation you like for the sides.

Comment: @Andreas I call BS.  You're again assuming your interpretation is the only one that is correct.  By alternating from one row to the next I mean that if an X was the last char on the previous row, then the next row would start with an O, and vice versa.  My code basically would FILL the entire box with this approach, except that the middle has been rendered with spaces instead of the char that would be there.

Comment: Well, you told me to "look again at the box in the original post at the VERY top", as if that is the definitive result. Yes, I didn't follow that in my answer, but then again, neither did you in this answer, so what did you actually intend to say with that reference? We both applied interpretations, but having all the rows print the same, without alternating, seems very wrong to me (yes, my opinion) for a question that's all about alternating.